# Meaning of the word remarkedly?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

Was just wondering whether 'remarkedly' is a word or not. When I typed it in Office Word it doesn't come up as a spelling error but I can't seem to find anything about it online or a concrete definition. Searching it up in Google Scholar however does show some uses of the word. I stumbled upon it after seeing the word 'markedly' in an academic journal article and then thinking how similar it would be to 'remarkably' if I added re- at the front and then finding out that it didn't show up as incorrect.

My feeling is that the two words markedly and remarkedly are variations of the same word as Merriam-Webster funnily puts markedly as the definition for remarkedly. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remarkedly

Comment: M-W entry qualifies it as a word. Why doubt it? Although *remarkedly* has a similar meaning to *markedly*, it has its uses as the use cases show.

Comment: @Kris Alright, I was just hoping for a better definition.

Comment: Even the OED just gives it as a derived form of "remarked" with no definition, just some examples (e.g. "Manfred Bikofzer had a remarkedly clear head for historical generalization."). I guess the meaning is supposed to be obvious.

Comment: @StuartF Yeah that seems true, it is not a hard word.

Comment: It's probably a confusion between _markedly_ and _remarkably_, both of which are common, and both of which mean about the same thing -- so much of a mark that one could remark on it.

Comment: I completely fail to understand this question. You've found the word in a dictionary. That gives you its meaning and let's you know it exists. What is the confusion? What are you actually asking?

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica Dw it's been answered in all the other comments. Was just looking for a better definition, because according to the dictionary markedly=remarkedly but Kris says it's not so you know, just a bit of ambiguity for a not so used word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remarkedly** is a word.

The Oxford English Dictionary classifies the word as a derived form of "[Remarked, adj. 1](https://oed.com/view/Entry/162077)":

> Marked, conspicuous, noted, notable. Now chiefly with modifying adverb.

For the adverb, the OED collects several examples starting from the 17th century:

> 1656   N. Stephens Plain Calculation Name & Number of Beast 181   The time when this Universal [Papal] Headship began visibly and **remarkedly** to appear, this is The Number of the Beast, and more specially of his Name and Headship.
>
> 1855   Putnam's Monthly Mag. Apr. 403/2   The species extends over the whole country, and in the South, where it attains its greatest size, it is **remarkedly** distinct from the lanceolata.
>
> 1871   S. Mateer Travancore 363   The discipline and general good deportment which is **remarkedly** observable in you.
>
> 1985   J. Kerman Musicol. 45   Manfred Bikofzer had a **remarkedly** clear head for historical generalization.
>
> 2007   Sunday Herald (Glasgow) 24 June 14/3   **Remarkedly** free with swearie words.

It's possible that modern usages are an error that comes from mixing up *remarkably* and *markedly*. That is hard to categorize though, and the possibility of error shouldn't be taken to suggest that *remarkedly* isn't a word. In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), I found this example from a 1990 PBS Newshour interview (4/30/1990) between the host, Mr. Lehrer, and then-Undersecretary of State for Political Affairs, Mr. Kimmitt, where the latter uses *remarkably* and *remarkedly* in close succession:

> I don't have any details on it. I would say that I have seen the same television pictures as you. I thought that he looked **remarkably** well and **remarkedly** well composed for a man who had been in captivity for almost four years.

Was he reduplicating the *re-* on the second utterance in error, intending *markedly*, or choosing *remarkedly* as a distinct echo of the first? There's too little information to know for sure what Mr. Kimmitt intended, so we have to judge based on what he actually said.

Given that it *is used*, and is defined and attested for some time, it makes sense to treat it as a distinct word with similar meaning to *markedly* or *remarkably*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The two words are remarkedly similar c: